# Filtrar registros asociados dependiendo del rol asignado

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

yo se sacar registros de la base de datos en laravel 6. El problema es el siguiente: mi página trata sobre noticias. El usuario administrador las ve todas, pero el que no lo es, también las ve. Yo lo que quiero hacer es que cada autor vea su noticia.

En MySQL tengo en la tabla noticia el campo autor, que tiene una clave foránea al campo id de la tabla de usuarios.

Actualmente no se cómo hacer que cada usuario vea sus propias noticias. A continuación dejaré el código del controlador, la ruta y la vista

Función del controlador para mostrar las noticias:

```
public function show2()
{
    $noticias = Noticia::all();
    return view('mostrar' , compact('noticias'));

}
```

Ruta:

```
 Route::get('/mostrar', 'crearNoticiaController@show2')->name('mostrar');
```

Vista:

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
    <div class="mostrarNoticia">
        <div class="imagen">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/{{$noticia->imagen}}" alt="imagen" width="250" align="left" id="imagen" /></td>
                 </tr>
            </table> 
        </div>   
        <div class="texto">
            <table border="1" width="254" class="titulo">
               <tr>
                    <td id="titulo"><strong>{{$noticia->titulo}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="1" width="254" class="contenido">
                <tr>
                    <td id="contenido">{!!$noticia->contenido!!}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            <form action="{{route ('borrar', $noticia->id) }}" class="botones" method="get" id="formularioAjax">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <a href="{{route ('editar', $noticia->id)}}"><button type="button" class="editarUsuario">Editar</button></a>
                <button type="submit" class="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
            </form>

    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún paquete para el manejo de roles?

Comment: No. Los pongo en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Podrías editar y agregar como esta declarado el tema de roles en tus tablas?

Comment: Además de lo anterior tienes las relaciones definidas en los modelos?

Comment: Tengo una tabla que se llama roles con su id, nombre, update_at y created_at. La tabla de los usuarios con id, nombre, etc... Y la tabla role_user con id, id_role y id_user para que así se asigne un rol a un usuario. Además en el model User.php tengo varias funciones para los roles, como el hasRole o authorizeRole.

Comment: En los modelos no tengo ninguna relación declarada. Solo la cree en la base de datos.

Comment: La cosa es que las relaciones están bien hechas, porque en la plantilla de los usuarios loggeados, hay un div que solo accede el usuario que tiene el rol administrador

Comment: Muchas gracias. Llevo con esto unos cuantos días la verdad. Entre esto y que estaba aprendiendo por otro lado jQuery no he podido avanzar mas.

Comment: El usuario ¿cuántos roles puede tener?

Comment: Únicamente un rol. En este caso son Admin y Cliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUCIONADO] En mi caso como lo que queria era que cada usuario viera sus noticias y el administrador todas, lo hice asi:

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')
<div> Aqui iria todo sobre las noticias</div>
@elseif(Auth::id() == $noticia->autor)
<div> Aqui iria todo sobre las noticias</div>
@endif
```

En este post tambien esta la manera de crear relaciones con los modelos y hacer consultas de mysql a mano de BetaM. Aprovechenla si no lo sabian

Answer (score 0):

**EJEMPLO**

Dadas las aclaraciones en la zona de comentarios, tu tienes:

- Una relación muchos a muchos entre users y roles (de ahi que tengas una tabla intermedia)
- Una relación de uno a muchos entre users y noticias
- La clase o modelo `User` deberá contar con 2 relaciones

  - Una relación con la tabla `noticias`
  - Una relación con la tabla `roles`
- El modelo Rol deberá tener una relación con la tabla `users`
- El modelo Noticia deberá tener una relación con la tabla User

**SECCIÓN 1**

Primero vas a obtener el nombre del rol de la persona que inició sesión ya que este valor será ocupado para nuestra segunda consulta:

```
    $id = 1;//posible id de la persona logueada
    $data = Rol::whereHas('users', function($query) use($id){
            $query->where('users.id', $id);
        })->select('name')->first();
```

La consulta anterior ya nos puede devolver el *string* del nombre del rol que tiene esa persona

**SECCIÓN 2**

Código de los modelos

Modelo User

```
class User extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "usuarios";
    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Noticia::class);
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rol::class, 'role_user');
    }
}
```

Modelo Noticia

```
class Noticia extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "noticias";
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Rol

```
class Rol extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "roles";
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user');
    }
}
```

**La consulta**

Vamos a valernos de Eloquent tanto de sus métodos:

- with
- whereHas

Como de sus relaciones para facilitar el trabajo:

- belongsToMany
- HasMany
- belongsTo

**Consulta final**

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use($data){
            $query->where('name', $data->name);
        })->with('noticias')->get();
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- Invocar al modelo `User` pero filtrar solamente por aquellos que su relación `roles` declarada mas arriba si retorne algún valor
- Como segundo argumento de la función `wherHas` vamos a filtrar de esos roles solo aquellos que sean de tipo `admin` o `guest` *eso lo decides tu*
- Finalmente le cargamos ahora con *eager loading* todas sus relaciones de `posts` que también fue declarada mas arriba
- Retomamos la variable `$data` y con la sintaxis de **->** accedemos a la propiedad o nombre de la columna de la tabla donde se almacena el nombre del rol a comparar

> La consulta anterior me dejará ya solo ver aquellos posts de acuerdo con mi perfil asignado, **el integrar esto a tu proyecto  te lo dejo a ti**

Por cierto si usas PHP 7.4 la consulta anterior quedaría así

```
User::whereHas('roles', fn($query) => $query->where('name', $data->name))
        ->with('noticias')
        ->get();
```

**AL FINAL**

Para que esta consulta se vuelva dinámica dependiendo de quien inició sesión, entonces **dentro del `where` intermedio quita el string que representa el rol y pàsale la variable que contiene ese valor cuando el usuario incia sesión**

Comment: Buenas. Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en dedicarme la respuesta. Estoy realizando las consultas y me salta un error que está intentando acceder a la propiedad de algo que no es un objeto. El error me lo da en el $data->name

Comment: Aparecía que no era un objeto porque la id 1 no existe en la base de datos. Ahora lo que hice fue: $user = User::find($id); y la id es igual a la variable user. Pero ahora salta el error este:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select `name` from `roles` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `role_user` on `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` where `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` and `users`.`id` = ?) limit 1)

Comment: Vale. Muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas. Ayer lo solucione con @if(Auth::id() == $noticia->autor). Lo habia intentado varias veces pero no se por que me daba error. Gracias por tu tiempo dedicado.

Comment: Resulta que en los modelos ya tenia las relaciones. Como hace tiempo que me puse con esa pagina no me acordaba.